# Solving the recurrence $a_n=4a_{n-1}+3$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How would I solve this recurrence relation?
$$a_n=4a_{n-1}+3$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  You'll find that you get significantly more (and better) help here if you start by showing us what you've tried and where you're getting stuck.  That means people can address your confusion instead of just answering the question for you.

Comment: Write the first few $a_n$ in terms of $a_0$, conjecture a general result, then prove it by induction.

Answer (score 2):

Put $u_n=a_n+1$ then
$$
u_{n+1} = a_{n+1}+1=4a_n+3+1=4\left(a_n+1\right)=4u_n
$$
Then $u_n=\left(a_0+1\right)4^n$ and
$$
a_n=\left(a_0+1\right)4^n-1
$$

Just a tip : If u have $a_{n+1} = \alpha a_n + \beta$, you can solve it by considering the auxiliary sequence $u_n = a_n - \frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$ if $\alpha \ne 1$.